# Python-Wing

Tags: python

Вот решил познакомится со средой программирования Python 3. Установил среду разработки Wing IDE 5. И вот, что получается:

Простенькая конструкция

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
```

не выполняется в среде Wing IDE 5 (не появляется окно), но в стандартной IDLE для Python 3 - все нормально (код выполняется с появлением окна). Что здесь не так? Спасибо.

Comment: @Anatoliy2015, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Результат исполнения этого кода в среде IDLE - стандартное окно, в среде Wing IDE 5 - этого не наблюдается. Phyton 3 установлен.

Comment: Есть какие-нибудь сообщения об ошибках?

Answer (score 0):

В конце программы нужно написать `mainloop()`